# Selenium IDE doc for devs

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I downloaded source code of Selenium IDE and I would like to edit a little bit Selenium IDE, but I can't find any doc about it.

Guys, do you know any doc for Selenium IDE developers?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever checked the issues in https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues ?
I think there are details that you want to know.